# How to handle many checkboxes in MVVM (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I have a list of extensions each with it's own checkbox that user needs to choose from:
[image]

In the end I need to have a List or an ObservableCollection of all the extensions chosen.

Doing this non-MVVM is quite straight forward. I create the event of Checked or Unchecked, and I add the content of the sender.

View:

```
<CheckBox Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked">exe</CheckBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
    private void ToggleButton_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ext = ((CheckBox) sender).Content.ToString();
        Model.FirstRun.ExcludeExt.Add(ext);
    }

    private void ToggleButton_OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ext = ((CheckBox)sender).Content.ToString();
        Model.FirstRun.ExcludeExt.Remove(ext);
    }
```

If I want to do this MVVM style, as far as I know - I have to create a property for each one of the checkboxes and bind them to the UI. This is a lot of work.

Is there any simpler way?

Comment: don't you think the UI little weird with lots of checkboxes? how about having combo box with check box in it?

Comment: @SushilMate would that make it easier to implement the binding in MVVM ?

Comment: btw this is just the barebone UI, a designer will later improve it.

Comment: You should first create a model. I.e 

class myCheckBox {
  boo Active; 
  string Name; 
}

class myCheckBoxList {
 List<myCheckBox >() ; 
 ... 
 Add(myCheckBox  paramMyCheckBox ) {
   myCheckBox .Add  (paramMyCheckBox ); 
 }
}

After 
Render the model on view 

*Sorry but I do not have a compiler here to write correct code

Comment: @DavidRefaeli Yes. code-wise, design-wise, effort-wise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should think about a structure first and then it is not that much work and pretty straight forward to use.

For example: you have groups of extensions. I would create somethink like this (just pseudo code; e.g. no `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented).

```
public class ExtensionGroup
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<ExtensionInfo> ExtensionInfos {get; set;}
}

public class ExtensionInfo
{
    public string Extension {get; set;}
    public bool IsChecked {get; set;}

    public ExtensionInfo(string extension)
    {
        Extension = extension;
    }
}
```

And in your ViewModel you can create

```
public ObservableCollection<ExtensionGroup> ExtensionGroups {get; set;}
```

Now you have to add the data like this

```
var extensionGroup = new ExtensionGroup{Name = "Executables"};
extensionGroup.ExtensionInfos.Add(new ExtensionInfo("exe");
extensionGroup.ExtensionInfos.Add(new ExtensionInfo("bat");
```

and after that you have a list with all groups including the extensions.

In you view you can bind this data and you're done. For the view you could use a ListView with a DataTemplate or some other items control.

Your view will get a lot easier with less code because you just have to specify the layout one time.

/edit
This is a sample implementation of the xaml. I used a `ItemsControl` instead of a `ListView`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ExtensionGroups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ExtensionInfos}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                      Content="{Binding Extension}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Looks like this (just added two groups with two extensions).
[image: Example]

Comment: And then how would you do the binding?

Comment: Amazing - I'm going to try it out :-)

Comment: Works like a charm. You just forgot (in the answer) to initalize (`ExtensionGroups = new ObservableCollection<ExtensionGroup>();             var extensionGroup = new ExtensionGroup { Name = "Executables", ExtensionInfos = new ObservableCollection<ExtensionInfo>()};
 `) and to add the extensionGroup to ExtensionGroups ( `ExtensionGroups.Add(extensionGroup);`
)